# performance counter

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I created a performance counter for my C# application. Its type is `NumberOfItems32`.
I don't know why but the Performance Monitor is displaying me on the y-axis only as maximum value only **100** when my counter is much more bigger than this for sure.
Do you know if this is the correct behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing correctly. Just perfmon is a bit stupid. Right click on your counter in main window, then properties, then Data tab, then play with Scale.